# How to add an image when generating a pdf-file with javascript. When adding the imageLoadFromURL no pdf is generated

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

I've got a problem with adding an image when generating a pdf-file with javascript. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="base64.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="sprintf.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jspdf.js"></script>



<script>

  function demo1() {

    var name = prompt('Name: ');
    var nachname=prompt('Nachname: ');
    var doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.setFontSize(22);    
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Der eingegebene Text');
    doc.setFontSize(16);
        doc.imageLoadFromUrl('image.jpg');
        doc.imagePlace(20, 40);


    doc.text(20, 30, 'Name: ' + name);
    doc.text(20,40,'Nachname:'+nachname);



    // Output as Data URI
    doc.output('datauri');

}

</script>

</head>

<body>

<h2> Ein Document </h2>

<a href="javascript:demo1()"> PDF erstellen </a>


</body>
</html>
```

Before adding

```
doc.imageLoadFromUrl('image.jpg');
doc.imagePlace(20, 40);
```

the code runs without picture. It starts with a demand note for the name and the second name, after this it generates a pdf-file. But when adding the imageLoad-Method there is no pdf-file generated. Does anyone konws how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I cant find imageLoadFromUrl function in jsPDF source.
What I would do is:

1. Take image data url with this site for example: [online image convertor](http://websemantics.co.uk/online_tools/image_to_data_uri_convertor/)
2. And use it like this:

   var imgData = 'data:image/jpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA...';// just an example
   doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', setX, setY, imageWidth, imageHeight);